# How to create an AWS ElastiCache cluster with 2 dumps

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have 2 Redis servers and I'm able to create AWS ElastiCache individually for each server, but I want to migrate 2 server's data into a single Redis cluster by using an S3 dump.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on AWS ElastiCache, but I think there is no AWS supported way to import two .rdb files in one redis cluster. You can do this manually using some open source tools. You can get the raw commands from each backup files and insert into new cluster one by one.

- Export your back to S3. This will create a .rdb file
- Download the .rdb file
- Then use one of the open source tools to
  parse the rdb file and insert the data into the existing elasticache
  redis

Two open source tools that will help you do this

- https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/blob/master/README.md#emitting-redis-protocol
- https://github.com/leonchen83/redis-cli-tool, see the
      redis-mass-insertion section